# Firebase hosting Page Not Found error on empty cache and hard reload

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-hosting

Firebase hosting is working fine!
But this displayed **Page Not Found** (attached an image) page in two cases:

1. Just after we deploy to Firebase hosting, 2-3 refresh is required to have expected page else it displayed Page Not Found page.
2. When we do empty cache and hard reload it shows **Page Not Found** page.

Note: The page is designed using Polymer Web Components.

Check this link - https://yesitesapp.com/products

Please suggested - if any configuration or any settings is required to work Firebase hosting properly.

[image]

Comment: if you want to hosting via web server apache then check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73746497/12771945

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a service worker installed that precaches `/products` and then servers that path from the client cache.

You have to modify your `firebase.json` config to serve your `index.html` file for all of the paths that your app uses. The Firebase docs have an [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites) that should look something like this where it says handle all paths (`**`) with `index.html`.

```
"hosting": {
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for subfolders too: `"manager/**"` to `"manager/index.html"`

Comment: Do you know such configuration for Heroku?

Comment: if you want to hosting via web server apache then check this stackoverflow.com/a/73746497/12771945