# Flutter web: Opening direct URL navigation working on local but not after deployment

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am trying to implement Flutter web url navigation in my application. When I am trying to open http://localhost:7357/privacy-policy directly it is opening fine on my local machine
but when I am trying to open the same URL directly after deploying it on server it is not loading and throwing me errors.
[image]
I am using Firebase to deploy my application.

Everything works fine after deploying when I am trying to access through the home page without any specific navigation for ex: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), the error comes when I am trying to directly access the page [www.example.com/privacy-policy](http://www.example.com/privacy-policy) instead of going through home page.

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: problem is your accessing private IP on deployment you have to make this ip public .

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh I didn't understand your comment, what IP are you talking about? My application is working fine after deployment, if I am trying to open a particular page directly through URL navigation that is throwing up this error.

Answer (score 5):

try adding "rewrites" in your firebase.json

```
"hosting": {
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
   } ]
}
```

and refer to this:
[When I refresh my website I get a 404. This is with Angular2 and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415725/when-i-refresh-my-website-i-get-a-404-this-is-with-angular2-and-firebase)

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `vercel` way (though not asked), as this has bugged me for a while:

Add `vercel.json` in the root of your project.

```json
{
  "rewrites":  [
    {"source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me too, i am facing same issue, flutter works when debugging but when hosting to web server apache, can't access direct url.
so this is my solution.

in main function get pathname.
and for routing system, i'am using [fluro](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro)

```
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart'; // for remove '#' on url
import 'dart:html' as html; 
void main() {
      RouteService.setupRouter();
      setPathUrlStrategy();
      final String pathName = html.window.location.pathname ?? '/';
      runApp(MyApp(pathName: pathName));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      String pathName;

      MyApp({Key? key, required this.pathName}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
               title: 'Flutter Demo',
               theme: ThemeData(
               primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
               textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(fontFamily: 
               'Open Sans'),
               ) ,
         initialRoute: pathName,
         onGenerateRoute: RouteService.router.generator,
      );
  }
}
```

create .htaccess
to load application through index.html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

after that i can access application via direct url.
example: /detail, /products or /product/2