# Flutter web redirects in cPanel when using go_router

Tags: flutter, cpanel, flutter-web, gorouter

How do I make the redirects in `go_router` package work correctly when uploading the website to cPanel? For example when I type in the url `www.website.com/contact` I need it to open the `/contact` route on my app. It works great when hosting locally and when I host it to Firebase with the rewrites file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71956918/12099062), but I am unable to make the redirects work in cPanel.

I have tried configuring the Redirects in cPanel, but if I redirect any page to `www.website.com` it just moves to the main page and if I redirect it to `www.website.com/index.html` it just shows `Exception: Bad State: No Element`.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it work by following a React app tutorial ([Deploy / Host your React App with cPanel in Under 5 Minutes](https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6)). I needed to manually add these contents to the `.htaccess` file in cPanel File Manager `public_html` folder (Note: You need to enable "Show hidden files" in order to see that file and if it does not exist, just create it).

Here is the complete `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yay, thank you for sharing this. This works like a charm. Was stuck on this for days.